# Locale Directory redirect using GeoIP using PHP code on laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, geolocation

Hello I stumbled on a code below:

```
<?php 
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])); 
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode']; 
if ($countrycode=='US')     header( 'Location: http://example1.com' ) ;
 else      
     header( 'Location: http://example2.com' ) ;  
 ?>
```

i am trying to use it home.blade.php on the top of it. its redirecting with giving error its redirecting way to many times.

and how to redirect with each page as well. like if page exists http://example1.com/page1 how to redirect in a way that redirects directly to http://example2.com/page2 when linked opened in google search

Comment: Does this file exist on exampl1.com or example2.com? It could be redirecting back to itself.

Comment: the file exists on exampl1.com it opens when its US ip if not it redirects many times

Comment: Try switching the URLS out for google.com and yahoo.com so you can see what's happening.. or switch the  header() function to echo. That way you can see what's happening "under the hood". My best guess is that the "location" header is resulting in the page redirecting back to itself... infinite loop. You have to be aware that the browser is the one actually performing the "redirect"-- not the server or the PHP code-- that's just telling the browser to reload a (hopefully different) URL.